# Mintty: preserve TAB characters while copy-pasting text via Ctrl+Ins followed by Shift-Ins

Tags: tabs, cygwin, copy-paste, mintty

While using text editors (vi, vim, nano, etc.) after copy-paste operation in Mintty via Ctrl+Ins followed by Shift-Ins the TAB characters are replaced with spaces. Proof:

```
text>    text1 //text to copy
text.....text1 //copied text
```

Why such behavior is by default?
How to preserve tab characters?